# Increasing enzyme concentration does not increase product formation

Tags: enzyme-kinetics

I am cutting DNA strand 40 nt long with enzyme with single cleavage site in DNA. At the lowest concentration of enzyme I use, 50% of the substrate is cleaved, however, increasing enzyme concentration such as using twice or four times more has no affect in the product formation, meaning that I still see only 50% of the DNA substrate is cleaved. Reaction time and temperature is constant in all cases. What could be causing this phenomenon?